# Art Director and Designers

Tags: designers

I am hiring three designers. Each will have the same obligations and produce the same work. should I hire one of them as Art Director to have some sort of hierarchy, or the three can be Art Directors because they will work in separate projects?

Comment: This is a question about human roles, leadership and power structure. Imagine if you started with 3 laborers, which one should be the boss? Can they all be the boss? How do you decide? Skill and experience and personality are common considerations. Age and seniority are important. Charm, persuasiveness, dominance and desire to be the boss play more of a role in these decisions than they should. It pains me to say it but people do seem to "fall into place" in a hierarchy. Some lead some follow.

Comment: I think this is pretty culture and organisational need dependent also. I mean i have worked in companies that had no management hierarchy whatsoever and i have worked in a company that had a level for each worker. It really depends do you want some of the people to devote some of or all their time to management or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can replace "Art director" by "cook/chef" and elicit the same answers, so this is not related to graphic design.

Comment: This was a question meant to designers. To understand in which way they prefer to work. Think that every professional should be more than a tool and be able to have a Voice in the kitchen

Answer (score 2):

Where I am, it's fairly common to have many Art directors in one agency. What is less common would be to have more than one Director of Creation. It makes sense they would all have the same title if they have the same obligations, regardless of if they work on the same projects or not.

Answer (score 1):

"Art Director" can me a number of different things:

- senior graphic designer
- graphic design manager
- artistic lead
- client liaison

And, often, some combination of the above.

As such, we simply can't answer this question for you without understanding the context of your company and your department's current needs.

Comment: The 3 designers will design product specs, independently, and will work each with a team that will build their Idea.

Comment: @NLuis what kind of product? What kind of team? How are the teams related? Are these internal products? External products? Who manages branding? UI specs? etc. etc. We simply don't know your business well enough to give you a good answer.